# Python button on/off logging

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to log the date and time a certain push button is pressed. I only want it to log (print) it once. At the moment it keeps on logging because of the `while True:`. How can I change the code to only log/print the action once?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

while True:
    machine_1 = GPIO.input(22)
    machine_2 = GPIO.input(27)
    machine_3 = GPIO.input(17)

if machine_1 == True:
    date_time_1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    split_datetime = date_time_1.split(" ")
    print "Machine 1 [ON]: ",split_datetime[0]," ",split_datetime[1]
time.sleep(0.2)

if machine_1 == False:
    date_time_1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    split_datetime = date_time_1.split(" ")
    print "Machine 1 [OFF]: ",split_datetime[0]," ",split_datetime[1]
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
machine_1_prev = False
while True:
    machine_1 = GPIO.input(22)

    if machine_1 and not machine_1_prev:
        print("Machine 1 [ON]:", datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elif not machine_1 and machine_1_prev:
        print("Machine 1 [OFF]:", datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    machine_1_prev = machine_1
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

What we are doing is having the loop remember the last state it saw the `machine_1` pin in, and react to the change in state between the last state and the current one.

The delay of 0.2 seconds is important for "debouncing," eliminating the pin switching rapidly between on and off for a fraction of a second while it is being depressed.

This blog post has some other ways to do it: http://shallowsky.com/blog/hardware/buttons-on-raspberry-pi.html

Comment: Thank you for replying. How do I avoid the `break` in order keep on logging every time the button is pushed and released? In other words, I do not want to exit the script.

Comment: I think I understand better. You want to print the log message once PER button press? And you find that as long as the button is pressed down, you get many log messages until you release it?

Comment: Ok, I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Thank you VERY much Sir. Your code is working as expected. I also learned from your code.